# Extracting data from same table which are not present in other users

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I want to set the context that I'm new to SQL and learning many things. I have encountered with a new requirement in sql query.

I have a table of commands which will have commands for different users where there will be a global user. Where primary key is combination of commandid, user, command category.

Pre-existing data has all commands for global user but not for other users. So I need to write a query from global user to other users. The challenge here is there may exist few commands which are part of one user and global user but not for other user.

The requirement is all commands with userid should be present for all other users.

I have created a query without challenge part like all users will not have one command and insert for all users.

steps followed:
1) Get all commands for global user
2) Get all commands for other users 
3) join them to get global set 
4) filter them or removing the already existing commands 
5) you will get required setcomamnds 
6) cross join with the other users

This works for me for normal case, but it doesn't return required output for the above table case. Thanks in advance. I'm using SQL2012

Query is:

```
  select * from (select c1.* from (select * from commands where userid=1) c1   left join (select * from commands where userid<>1) c2 on c1.commandid = c2.commandid where c2.userid is null) allcommands cross join (select distinct userid from commands where userID<>1) users
```

Example table with Challenge:

```
UserID CommandID Category CommandName Shortcut
 1       1         Menu     File        Ctrl+F
 1       2         Menu     Save        Ctrl+S
 1       3         Menu     Copy        Ctrl+C
 1       4         Menu     Delete      Ctrl+D
 2       1         Menu     File        Ctrl+F
 2       2         Menu     Save        Ctrl+S
 2       3         Menu     Copy        Ctrl+C
 3       1         Menu     File        Ctrl+F
 3       2         Menu     Save        Ctrl+S
 3       4         Menu     Delete      Ctrl+D
 4       1         Menu     File        Ctrl+F
 4       2         Menu     Save        Ctrl+S
```

Update with working Query

Comment: join adds columns. You don't seem to want that; you want to add rows. try using UNION

Comment: that query that you posted, doesn't seems like a working query. This is your current working query ?

Comment: Its working but it had few syntax issues. Sorry couldn't access SQL editor as of now so cannot give perfect working query. I think it has few minor syntax corrections need to be done. Again apologies for not putting proper query.

Comment: Don't use `=NULL`. NULL != NULL.  You should use `IS NULL`. It isn't clear what you're asking here - perhaps provide the actual table structure as well as the example output.

Comment: The where clause (`where c2.userid is null`) changes the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: I got an alternative option to achieve this but I think it is not a good solution as performance wise. The query is select allusers.userID,allcommands.commandid,allcommands.commandname from ((select * from commands where userID =1 ) allcommands
  cross join 
 (select distinct userid from commands where userID <>1) allusers)
  except
 (select userID,commandid,commandname from commands where userID <>1)

Can anyone help me in fine tuning this query